# VARCHAR2 Content lost during call to Oracle from JBoss

Tags: oracle, jboss, struts2

Really weird.

I have an Oracle function

```
function highlightDesc(desc IN VARCHAR2, keyword IN VARCHAR2) return VARCHAR2
return 'paragraphtag' || 
       REPLACE(desc, keyword, 'boldtag' || keyword || 'boldtag') || 'paragraphtag';
```

this gets called this way

```
select a.*, highlightDesc(a.Desc) as highlightedDesc
from tablea a
```

The weird thing is that when I call this sql from within sqlplus or plsql developer the highlightedDesc column contains all the right markup.

When I call it from Junit, I get all the right markup.

When I call it from a struts2 app running on jboss(winxp/redhat) with the oracle thin drivers, 
I get the enclosing paragraphtag tags and the content but not the boldtag .

Does that make sense? 
Any thoughts?

Edit:

I apologize, I cant log into SO from work. Lame I know.

I am using the commons dbutils queryrunner (BeanListHandler) to execute the sql from a java class. 
My action is doing nothing but calling my service class and setting the value.

I looked at the src for queryrunner, it ends up calling a class called BeanProcessor which gets the highlightedDesc column as a String via rs.getString(index);

I thought it might be an encoding problem??? so I tried to change the jvm encoding and also the jboss encoding, but it had no effect. 
I think I might see if converting the character set in oracle has any effect?

Thanks.

Comment: Please post the code involved in the call, if the code is in an S2 action then post the action.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely, the `keyword` isn't passed correctly to the function, so the `REPLACE` function does effectively nothing.

Comment: Thanks, you are right, I realized that the parameter being passed in from the web page was in mixed case, so I changed the call from Replace to Regex_replace with the 'i' option...